# FizzBuzz Program: Function not returning correctly even when its conditionals are met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a program that prints a "fizz-buzz" list for 100 numbers.

Fizz-Buzz is a game where you attempt to list numbers in order, but if a number is a multiple of 3, you say fizz and if a number is a multiple of 5 you say buzz, if it's both you say "fizzbuzz".

For 10 number it would be something like `1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz`.

```
x = 1

while(x < 10):

    if x % 3 == 0:
        fizzint = True
    elif x % 3 != 0:
        fizzint = False

    if x % 5 == 0:
        buzzint = True
    elif x % 5 != 0:
        buzzint = False


    if fizzint == True and buzzint == True:
        print("FizzBuzz \n")

    if fizzint == False and buzzint == False:
        print(x)
        print("\n")

    if fizzint == True and buzzint == True:
        print("Fizz \n")

    if fizzint == True and buzzint == True:
        print("Buzz \n")

    x = x+1
```

The issue is that the program simply ignores all multiples of 3 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that three of your conditions are the same:

```
if fizzint == True and buzzint == True:
if fizzint == True and buzzint == True:
if fizzint == True and buzzint == True:
```

The first one is correct, but the third one should be:

```
if fizzint == True:
```

and the fourth one should be:

```
if buzzint == True:
```

Which prints the correct output.

Notice that since `fizzint` and `buzzint` are booleans, you don't actually have to compare to `True` and `False` -- youc an simply say `if fizzint` or `if not fizzint`.

Also, your fizzint-setting statements can be simplified as well:

```
fizzint = x % 3 == 0
buzzint = x % 5 == 0
```

since `x % 3 == 0` already returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: I'd also like to add that `bool(x%3)` works too since zeroes are False in Python. Cheers!